# how to findout local time using utcoffset and countryname in python

Tags: python, timezone

I have countrynames and utcoffset of that country
How to find out out local time in that country using utcoffset?

Comment: Just get the UTC hour and add the offset... was that your question?

Comment: @pconcepcion: utc offset may change through the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for looking up timezones by location. Maybe something like this:

```
>>> import pytz, datetime
>>> pytz.country_timezones['de']
['Europe/Berlin']
>>> matching_tzs = [t for t in pytz.country_timezones['de'] if pytz.timezone(t)._utcoffset.total_seconds() == 3600]
>>> datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone(matching_tzs[0]))
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 6, 17, 5, 26, 174828, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: +1 for pytz. But there is no need to use private `_utcoffset` that might yield wrong results because the offset may depend on time. You could [use `.utcoffset()` method instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20336532/4279)

Answer (score 1):

call `datetime.now()` with the time zone (as a `tzinfo` object) as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

A country may span several timezones. A utc offset for a place may change through the time.

Given a country code and a utc offset, you could try to find matching timezone from Olson tz database for the current time. Here's variant of [@Mu Mind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5913299/4279) that takes into account current time (otherwise the result can be unexpected for some timezones):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

country_code, utc_offset = 'de', timedelta(hours=1)

# find matching timezones and print corresponding local time
now_in_utc = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
for zonename in pytz.country_timezones[country_code]:
    tz = pytz.timezone(zonename)
    local_time = now_in_utc.astimezone(tz)
    if tz.utcoffset(local_time) == utc_offset: #NOTE: utc offset depends on time
       print("%s\t%s" % (tz.zone, local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z")))
```

#### Output

```
Europe/Berlin   2013-12-02 20:42:49 CET+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the current `TZ` environ variable value and then do

```
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'US/Eastern'
>>> time.tzset()
```

And for the library, whatever time function you use will be for the US/Eastern timezone, you c can reset it back to original one later.

Example usage:

```
>>> time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'22:54:11 05/06/11 SGT'
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'US/Eastern'
>>> time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'10:54:30 05/06/11 EDT'
```

Please refer to [time module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) documentation for examples.

Answer (score 0):

working code

```
utcoffset='+5:30'
utctime=datetime.datetime.utcnow()      
hr=utcoffset[0:utcoffset.find(':')]
min=utcoffset[utcoffset.find(':')+1:]
datetimeofclient=datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hr),minutes=int(min))
```